# place MaterialDrawer above actionbar

Tags: android, materialdrawer

How I can put [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) menu above ActionBar? Now, when I open MaterialDrawer menu, my ActionBar is on top of it. Is there is any thing like Z-index in CSS? :D
My application style:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
  </style>
  <style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/yellow_dark</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

My MaterialDrawer initialization code:

```
DrawerBuilder().withActivity(activity).addDrawerItems(...).withSelectedItem(-1).withTranslucentStatusBar(false).withActionBarDrawerToggle(false).build()
```

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Comment: Solution - is replase ActionBar with [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already noted by @igor_rb this is only possible if you switch from an `ActionBar` to a `Toolbar`.

See the following already answered issues at github
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/523
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/522
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/333

Switching to a `Toolbar` is really easy.

---

Use an `AppCompatActivity`
Define the `Toolbar` within your layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:elevation="4dp" />
```

Set the `Toolbar` as `SupportActionBar`

```
// Handle Toolbar
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

**Done**